# El widget Combobox no muestra los valores de su lista asignada

Tags: combobox

Estoy teniendo problemas con el Widget Combobox debido a que este no muestra los registros que se encuentran en la lista asignada `self.list_1=Combobox(self.LF2,**values=self.options**,state="readonly").grid(pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky=W)`, A lista self.options toma los registros de los nombres de las tablas de la base de datos.

La idea principal de esto es que los los nombres de las tablas contenidas en sq.db se puedan ver en el combobox con la finalidad de poder clickear sobre ellos y así generar consultas SQL.

El problema que tengo es que en la lista desplegable no aparecen los registros del nombre de las tablas.

Adjunto los códigos. Gracias por su ayuda

Consideraciones:

1. Ya se normalizó la tupla generada por el método fechtall().
2. No sé si existe problema debido al que el Widget combobox está dentro de un Wiget LabelFrame el cual está dentro de un Frame() y a su vez este está dentro de la raiz().

Código 1-------------(def frame_dbm(self)) el método en el que está contenido el combobox.

"

```
#LIBRERÍAS DE PYTHON--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import csv
import sys, webbrowser, platform
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os
import locale
import datetime 
import io
import codecs 
import shlex

# LIBERÍAS DEL SISTEMA PARA EL MÓDULO TKINTER----------------------------------------------------------

from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog, font, ttk, messagebox
from tkinter import LEFT, TOP, X, FLAT, RAISED
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# LIBRERÍAS PROPIAS DE PARADIGM-----------------------------------------------------------------------

from Functions_DB.Create_DB import*
from Data_Bases.DB_Manager import*


# CLASE QUE GENERA EL GUI-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class App():

    def __init__(self,img_carpeta,iconos):

        self.img_carpeta=img_carpeta
        self.iconos=iconos
        self.ttk_Win=Tk()
        self.icono0=PhotoImage(file=self.iconos[0])
        self.ttk_Win.iconphoto(self.ttk_Win,self.icono0)
        self.ttk_Win.title("PARADIGM 1.0.0")
        self.ttk_Win.option_add('*tearoff',FALSE)
        self.ttk_Win.minsize(1000,450)
        self.ttk_Win.resizable(True,True)

        #VARIABLES DE AYUDA-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.co0=0
        self.sentinel=False
        
        #VARIABLES PARA LA BASE DE DATOS---------------------------------------------------------------

        self.DB=DB_Adress()
        self.GI=Gen_info()
        
        #ICONOS DEL SISTEMA-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.icono1=PhotoImage(file=self.iconos[1])
        self.icono2=PhotoImage(file=self.iconos[2])
        self.icono3=PhotoImage(file=self.iconos[3])
        self.icono4=PhotoImage(file=self.iconos[4])

        
        #CREA EL MENÚ DEL SISTEMA-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.menubar=Menu(self.ttk_Win) 
        self.ttk_Win.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.menu_File=Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_File, label='File')
        self.menu_File.add_command(label='New Project',underline=0,image=self.icono2,
        command=lambda:[self.New_Project(),self.on_off()],accelerator="Ctrl+N",compound=LEFT)#command=lambda:[self.frame_initial_data(),self.new_db()] hacer dos procesos con un mismo elemento 
        self.menu_File.add_command(label='Open Project...',underline=0,image=self.icono1,
        command=lambda:[self.on_off()],accelerator="Ctrl+O",compound=LEFT)
        self.menu_File.add_command(label='Save',underline=0,image=self.icono3, accelerator="Ctrl+S",compound=LEFT,state="disable")
        self.menu_File.add_command(label='Save as',underline=0,image=self.icono4,
        command=lambda:[""],accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+S",compound=LEFT,state="disable")
        self.menu_File.add_separator()
        self.menu_File.add_command(label='Exit',accelerator="Ctrl+Q",command=self.Exit)


        self.menu_View=Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_View, label='View')

        self.menu_Tools=Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_Tools, label='Tools')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Loading Box')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Voltage Droop')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Level voltage required')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Economic calculation of conductors')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Check of conductor according IEC 60909')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Loss energy calculating')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Insulation coordination in MV')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Shielding')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='DPS System')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Electromagnetical filed calculating')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Cable Tray')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Canalization')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Mechanical calculating of structures')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Short circuit analisys & Earth fault')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Earth system calculating')
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Arc flash')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Tools.add_command(label='Transformer calculating')

        self.menu_Docs=Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_Docs, label='Manager file')
        self.menu_Docs.add_command(label='RETIE Summary')
        self.menu_Docs.add_command(label='RETILAP Summary')
        self.menu_Tools.add_separator()
        self.menu_Docs.add_cascade(label='Particular specificactions')
        self.menu_Docs.add_cascade(label='General specificactions')
        self.menu_Docs.add_separator()
        self.menu_Docs.add_command(label='Budget')
        self.menu_Docs.add_separator()
        self.menu_Docs.add_command(label='Manager database system',command=self.mdbs)

        self.menu_Info=Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_Info, label='Help')

        #FRAMES DEL LA APP---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #CREA LA BARRA DE HERRAMIENTAS---------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.toolbar=Frame(self.ttk_Win,relief=RAISED,bd=0)
        self.toolbar.config(bg="white")
        self.toolbar.pack(fill=X)

        B_New_F=Button(self.toolbar,image=self.icono2,relief=RIDGE,command=lambda:[self.New_Project(),self.on_off()])
        B_New_F.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1)

        B_Open_F=Button(self.toolbar,image=self.icono1,relief=RIDGE)
        B_Open_F.pack(side=LEFT,padx=1,pady=1)

        #FRAME INFERIOR------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.down_frame=Frame(self.ttk_Win,relief=GROOVE,bd=1)
        self.down_frame.config(bg="white",height="30")
        self.down_frame.pack(fill="x",side="bottom")

        #FRAME IZQUIERDO-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.left_frame=Frame(self.ttk_Win,relief=GROOVE,bd=1)
        self.left_frame.config(bg="white",width="200")
        self.left_frame.pack(fill="y", side="left")

        #FRAME PRINCIPAL-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.ppal_frame=Frame(self.ttk_Win,relief=GROOVE,bd=1)
        self.ppal_frame.config(bg="white")
        self.ppal_frame.pack(fill="both",side="left",expand=1)

        
        
        #CREA LA BARRA DE HERRAMIENTAS FLOTANTE------------------------------------------------------------VERIFICAR EL USO DEL FRAME DEBIDO A QUE 
        #gENERA ERROR CON EL lABELfRAME DEBIDO A QUE EXISTE UN ERROR CON EL PACK
        #self.toolbar=Frame(self.ttk_Win,relief=GROOVE,bd=2,bg="Blue")
        #self.toolbar.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=EW)
                
        #B_New_F=Button(self.toolbar,image=self.icono2,relief=RIDGE,command=lambda:[self.New_Project(),self.on_off()])
        #B_New_F.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=2,pady=1)

        #B_Open_F=Button(self.toolbar,image=self.icono1, relief=RIDGE)
        #B_Open_F.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=2,pady=1)
        
        #self.toolbar.pack(fill=X)



        #TECLAS DE ACCESO RÁPIDO--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        self.ttk_Win.bind("<Control-q>",lambda event:[self.Exit()])
        self.ttk_Win.bind("<Control-n>",lambda event:[self.New_Project(),self.on_off()])
        self.ttk_Win.bind("<Control-o>",lambda event:[self.on_off()])
        self.ttk_Win.bind("<Control-Shift-s>",lambda event:[""])


        #FUNCIONES DEL GUI--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            
        #FUNCIONES DEL BOTÓN NEW_PROJECT-------------------------------------------------------------------

    def on_off(self):# Permite apagar o encender íconos en el desplegable FILE-----------------------------
        if self.DB.checker()==True:
            self.menu_File.entryconfig(index="Save as",state="active")
            self.menu_File.entryconfig(index="Save",state="active")

    def New_Project(self):# Función  nuevo proyecto asiganada al botón y al menú desplegable--------------
        self.DB.checker()
        print(self.DB.checker())
        if self.DB.checker()==True:
            np1=messagebox.askyesnocancel("PARADIGM","Currently exist an open project. Do you want save it?")
            if np1==True:
                #Actualizar la base de datos abierta. 
                #Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos.
                self.DB.Close_db()
                #Crear un nuevo proyecto de acuerdo con la función self.DB.new_db()
                self.DB.Create_db() 
            if np1==False:
                #Eliminar la conexión con la base de datos previa
                self.DB.Close_db()
                self.DB.Create_db()
        else:
            self.DB.Create_db()

        #FUNCIONES DEL COMANDO QUIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def Exit(self):#Destruye el GUI y pregunta si se desean guardar cambios en la base de datos-------------

        Qt=messagebox.askyesnocancel("PARADIGM","Do you want save changes?")
        if Qt==True:
            A=1 # Acá debe desecadenar la función de actualización de la base de datos 
        elif Qt==False:
            self.ttk_Win.destroy()

        #FUNCIÓN DEL COMANDO SQL MANAGER SYSTEM -----------------------------------------------------------

    def mdbs(self):
        if self.sentinel==False:
            self.edit_win=Toplevel()
            self.edit_win.title('User Autentication')
            self.edit_win.resizable(0,0)
            self.edit_win.bind('<Return>',lambda event:[self.GI.sql_password(esp1.get(),esp2.get()),verify()])
        
            self.LF1=LabelFrame(self.edit_win, text="Login: ")
            self.LF1.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=5,pady=10)
            Label(self.LF1, text="User: ").grid(pady=5,row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
            esp1=Entry(self.LF1,width=40)
            esp1.grid(padx=5,row=0, column=1)
        
            Label(self.LF1,text="Password: ").grid(pady=5,  row=1, column=0, sticky = W)
            esp2=Entry(self.LF1,show="*",width=40)
            esp2.grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)
        
            Button(self.LF1, text="Login",command=lambda:[self.GI.sql_password(esp1.get(),esp2.get()),verify()],
                width=40).grid(padx=5, pady=5,row=3, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky = W + E)

            def verify():
                if self.GI.sql_password(esp1.get(),esp2.get()):
                    self.sentinel=True # se deben guardadr cambios y luego desplegar asignar el valor de False a la variable para poder ingresar en otra ocasión...
                    self.edit_win.destroy()
                    #Aquí se debe disparar el método que ejecuta el frame que tiene los datos de la base de datos manager
                    self.frame_dbm()
                else:
                    Label(self.LF1, text="The user or password is invalid").grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
        
            self.edit_win.mainloop()

    def frame_dbm(self): # NNo olvidar dar  self.sentinel el valor  False !!!!! Generar un FRame BASE para integrar el Label Frame
        self.LF2=LabelFrame(self.left_frame,bg="white", text="System's Data")
        self.LF2.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=2,pady=10)
        self.options=self.GI.view_table_log()
        self.list_1=Combobox(self.LF2,values=self.options,state="readonly").grid(pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        print(self.options)
        
# CREADOR DEL GUI-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def f_verificar_iconos(iconos): # Verifica la existencia de iconos en la carpeta images---------------------       
    
    for icono in iconos:
        if not os.path.exists(icono):
            print('Icono no encontrado:', icono)
            return(1)
    return(0)

def main():

    app_carpeta = os.getcwd()
    img_carpeta = (app_carpeta + os.sep + "images" + os.sep)
    
    # Acá se introduce el vector de imágenes---------------------------------------------------------------   
    iconos = (img_carpeta+"statistics.png",
        img_carpeta+"open_folder.png",
        img_carpeta+"New_file.png",
        img_carpeta+"Save.png",
        img_carpeta+"Save as.png")
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

    error1 = f_verificar_iconos(iconos)
       
    if not error1:
        app=App(img_carpeta, iconos)
        app.ttk_Win.mainloop()
    return(0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
"
```

Código 2 -----------

"

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os

class Gen_info:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        folder=os.getcwd()
        db_folder=(folder+os.sep+"Data_Bases"+os.sep)
        self.db_name=(db_folder+'database.db')
        print(self.db_name)

        self.view_table_log()

    def sql_password(self,esp1,esp2):
            query='SELECT * FROM Users_guide WHERE user=? AND password=?'
            parameters=(esp1,esp2)
            self.run_query(query,parameters)
            if self.result.fetchall():
                return True
            else:
                return False
                

    def validation(self,data1,data2):
        return len(data1)!=0 and len(data2)!=0

    
    def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
        with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            self.cursor=conn.cursor()
            self.result=self.cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return self.result

    def view_table_log(self):
        query='SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name'
        self.run_query(query)
        array=[item[0]for item in self.cursor.fetchall()]
        print(array)
```

"